# VIM: .vimrc not working as expected on Mint13 XFCE, works on MacVim

Tags: vim, vundle

Vim-newbie here...
I've been learning vim at work using a Mac.

I added my .vimrc to my github repo and expected Vundle to
download everything and have vim working the same on my home Mint 13 laptop.

I've linked  my ~/.vim/.vimrc to ~/.vimrc. 
I followed [these](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source) instructions for building vim 7.4 and having a working vim.

I know that some parts of the .vimrc file are read, b/c my 
remapped esc sequence is working.

Nothing else appears to work, not even line numbers.

vim --version

vim --version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Feb 25 2015 20:30:46)
Included patches: 1-640
```

vimrc

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins


" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

" Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.
Bundle 'nanotech/jellybeans.vim'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Bundle 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'
Bundle 'fs111/pydoc.vim'
Bundle 'hdima/python-syntax'
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Bundle 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'
Bundle 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Bundle 'kien/rainbow_parentheses.vim'
call vundle#end()            " required

filetype plugin indent on    " required
syntax enable
set foldmethod=indent
set foldlevel=99
setlocal foldmethod=indent

set background=dark
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set shiftround
set number
let mapleader=","
set hlsearch
set mouse=a
set nojoinspaces
set smarttab

nnoremap <leader>n :NERDTree<CR>
imap fj <Esc> 
colorscheme jellybeans 
" rainbow parens
au VimEnter * RainbowParenthesesToggle
au Syntax * RainbowParenthesesLoadRound
au Syntax * RainbowParenthesesLoadSquare
au Syntax * RainbowParenthesesLoadBraces
```

Comment: Have you checked the permissions, file owner, etc? Whatever user you run vim as (`whoami`) has to be able to read it. Line endings (`\r` vs `\n`) might also be messed up if you're transferring the file between systems, but that might not be relevant in this case.

Comment: How exactly have you linked this .vimrc file?
You might already know this, but to make vundle download everything you should first download it with:
`git clone https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim`
and then run :PluginInstall inside vim.

Comment: I think you have to further investigate what is the problem before you can solve it. Does the problem is with your Vim *compilation/installation* or with the loading of your Vim *configuration*? Try running the commands by hand -- if they doesn't work, forget about your configuration and focus on the vim compilation. For instance, you mentioned line numbers - does it works if you enter `:set number` on a running instance?

Comment: Thanks to everyone: I'll check permission, I do have Vundle installed separately PluginInstall "worked", and I like the idea of running each command separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear, that once again I've been bitten by XFCE.

[This link](https://superuser.com/questions/749585/i-cant-get-xfce-terminal-to-display-vims-colorschemes) gave me the hint I needed, setting my terminal
colos with:

```
set t_Co=256
```

Now more features are working as I expected, except that the color scheme
jellybeans is no longer so great.

Rainbowparens is not working.

EDIT:
Using more colors allows rainbow parens to work...

```
set t_Co=512
```